# html area map shifting as monitor resolution changes

Tags: jquery, html

I have a large background photo with certain parts of the image delineated by area tags to make an image map.

Here is the first portion of the image map:

```
<img id="mainbkgrnd" src="./images/everythingistemporary2.jpg" width="100%" 
            height="auto" alt="Home" usemap="#homemap">
    <map name="homemap">
        <area class="areamap" id="map_comments" shape="rect" 
        coords="880,140,1000,360" href="comments.php" alt="Comments"/>
```

When the user hovers over a delineated area, a corresponding text label appears in a div in the top right of the image. Here is the code for that div:

```
</map> 
<div id="pagename"></div>
```

Here is the jquery that makes the label appear:

```
$(function() {
    $('area').hover( 
        function(event) {
            var area = this.id.split('map_')[1];
            if (area == 'comments') {
                pn.css('left',1100);
                pn.html('Comments');
            }else if (area == 'shorts') {
                pn.css('left',1100);
                pn.html('Shorts');
```

The problem is that on monitors of different sizes, the delineated areas no longer match their desired locations -- they move around. So does the div in which the labels appear.

What is the best way to fix this?

ALSO, Internet Explorer will not show the labels in the div at all. Is there a reason why?

Comment: (1) I guess that the map only applies to 100% scaling and that something is rescaling the image, probably a CSS directive. (2) To fix the IE problem, try removing the "map_" prefix with `.replace(...)` instead of `split('map_')[1]`.

Comment: More info: the image is being rescaled by `width="100%"`, ie 100% of its container's width. Therefore the image map needs to be dynamically adjusted to the same resultant scale.

Comment: Try [imagemapster](http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster/)'s `scaleMap()` or `resize()`.

Comment: Beetroot-Beetroot - Thank you for your suggestions. I tried the .replace() method for IE but sadly it didn't make a difference. Either way, the area var does contain the right value when alert()'ed (even in IE). I'll give imagemapster a look, Thanks.

Comment: Hmm, if it's not `.split()` then maybe it's the `css()` statements. Try `pn.css('left','1100px');`. Also, you may be able to avoid the `if(){...} else {...}` structure with the single line `pn.css('left','1100px').html($(this).attr('alt'));` but only if it's 1100px in all cases.

Comment: Sorry for delay responding. I was able to resolve this by using the imagemapster plugin - scaleMap is the default setting, and it works with IE. Also, the tips feature solved the IE problem with displaying the div. SO - Please change (or augment) your comment to an answer and I'll award the question to you. Thanks again for your great ideas.

Comment: Gibberish, that's really fantastic news! Thank you for asking your question - without it, I wouldn't have found ImageMapster. I've added a proper answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gibberish,

Try the **[ImageMapster](http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster/)** jQuery plugin, which acts on image maps to offer (at v1.2.6) the following features :

- Highlight and select areas
- Cool effects by using an alternate image
- Bind the image map to an external list
- Show floating tooltips for areas or area groups
- Grouping and exclusion masks to create complex functionality
- Automatic scaling of imagemaps to any display size, even while active

The feature you need is the last one listed.

I've not used ImageMapster myself, but the **[demos](http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster/default.aspx?demos.html)** are very impressive and indicative of a well written plugin.

Comment: Just today found [the SO API](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/) that allows me to [search through previously asked questions for any without an accepted answer.](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/unaccepted-questions-on-users)  Sorry took so long to accept this answer, it was buried under years of activity. Your answer was absolutely correct and I have now been using this excellent plugin for years. Thanks very much for your help. accept +1